# The product of distribution taken over Unions

Tags: probability, products

I have a probability problem as follow:

$\mathbb{P}\big[\mathop{\arg\sup}_{x \in \bigcup_{i\in \{1,2\}} \Phi_{k,i} } \mathcal{f}(x )\geq y \big] = 1-\mathop{\prod}_{x \in \bigcup_{i\in \{1,2\}} \Phi_{k,i} } \mathbb{P}\big[  \mathcal{f}(x )\leq y \big]$

$\Phi_k$ is a 2D Poisson Point process, so $x$ is a point.
$f : \mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$

This might be a simple question but I need some hint. How can I expand the product?

Comment: What is the random variable? What are the assumptions on $f$, $\Phi$?

Comment: sorry for the lack of sufficient information. Post is edited

Comment: What is your question? I guess you want to prove the equality of the first equation.